# Why does my element shift down when selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm building a dashboard type display that shows several small items across the top. When the user clicks on one of the items, the others get smaller and the selected one expands. That works as expected except that the selected item seems to be shifting down. When I inspect with Chrome it doesn't show anything causing the shift. If I only have one item on page, this doesn't seem to happen.

There as a jsFiddle of the problem here: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MaelstromCdn/c54f4/)

Sample page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Explode</title>
    <style>
        .mycontent {
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
        }

        .myitem {
            height: 80px;
            width: 150px;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 10px;
            display: inline-block;
            background-color: blue;
            color: white;
            border: 1px solid #1e5799;
        }

        .myitem.expand {
            height: 200px;
            width: 300px;
        }

        .myitem.mycollapse {
            width: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="mycontent">
        <div class="myitem">Item 1</div>
        <div class="myitem">Item 2</div>
        <div class="myitem">Item 3</div>
        <div class="myitem">Item 4</div>
    </div>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(".myitem").click(function (e) {
            $(".myitem.expand, .myitem.mycollapse").removeClass("expand mycollapse");
            $(".myitem").not(e.target).addClass("mycollapse");
            $(e.target).addClass("expand");
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tested in Chrome 33.0.1750.117 and Firefox 27.0.1 with the same result.

Any ideas what's causing the shift?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set:

```
vertical-align: top;
```

Comment: The speed of answers on here always amazes me. This fixed it, thanks! Will accept in a couple minutes when it lets me.

Answer (score 1):

float:left; is missing in .myitem

Comment: This worked too, I accepted the other one as it gives me a bit more layout flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

You have used inline-block as display style for 3 divs. Inline elements are similar to text elements that flow with the document. The extra space you see at the top is due to the current font size for the inline elements. [ Try changing the font size of all the divs to 20 or 30 px, the top space increases and try font-size:0px all the three boxes will align ].

If you want the elements to flow from left to right, you can use float:left property. Try this fiddle, if this is the output that you are expecting

http://jsfiddle.net/QvM5W/

```
.mycontent {
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}
.myitem {
height: 80px;
width: 150px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 10px;
float:left;
background-color: blue;
color: white;
border: 1px solid #1e5799;
}
.myitem.expand {
height: 200px;
width: 300px;
}
.myitem.mycollapse {
width: 10px;
}
```